# What is causing a script to run when I change to a certain user?

Tags: command-line, scripts, login, .profile

I have a certain user account on a box I'm working on. Whenever I log into or su to that user, a script comes up that restricts my usage of the server. This is intended and I wanted to modify it but cannot find where it lives, nor do I knows the scripts name.

I've checked profile.d but don't see any scripts there. The script in question is basically a menu that lets the user do a couple of things, like this: http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_adv_tput.php. Ctrl + c does not exit the script as well.

Anyone know other places I could check for scripts that run as you log into a specific user account?

Comment: How does it restrict you? Have you checked `/etc/security/limits.conf`?

Comment: Did you check the users .bashrc ?

Comment: @IzznogooooD The user doesn't have a /home directory in this case. Would bashrc still apply? If so, where can I find it?

Comment: Global settings are done in `/etc/profile` , `/etc/profile.d` , `/etc/bash.bashrc` , and some of those `pam` scripts, but i don't have knowledge of those

Comment: @muru There is nothing but commented lines in the limits.conf. It restricts usage in the sense that the only options in the interactive shell script menu are changing IP and shutting down/restarting.

Comment: @Thisisstackoverflow No :)

Comment: @IzznogooooD is the user's shell set to `/bin/bash` or something else?

Comment: @muru Ah thank you. The passwd file points to the unique shell script instead of the normal bin/bash or bin/sh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user's shell was actually pointing to the custom menu driven script in question. I found this by catting the /etc/passwd file.